# Tweepy code does not work to collect Tweets -- Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am attempting to collect tweets with tweepy in python. However, the cursor function does not appear to work. The error says that 'API' object has no attribute 'search' .

Code:

```
from config import *
import tweepy
import datetime

access_token="ACCESS TOKEN HERE"
access_token_secret="ACCESS TOKEN SECRET HERE"
consumer_key="CONSUMER KEY HERE"
consumer_secret="CONSUMER KEY SECRET HERE"
auth= tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday= today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today, yesterday

tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(tweepy.api.search, q="#Covid-19 since:" + str(yesterday)+ " 
until:" + str(today),tweet_mode='extended', lang='it').items()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Tweepy v4 this has changed to `API.search_tweets()` https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/changelog.html#version-4-0-0

Comment: If this was the correct answer please mark this as as the solution - I can see you are now using the method I suggested, in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208155/tweepy-error-when-trying-to-gather-tweets). Thanks.