# Tweepy error when trying to gather Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get Tweets using the Tweepy module in Python. However, whenever I try to collect Tweets using the `tweepy.Cursor` function, it returns the error:

```
TweepyException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a26c992842dc> in <module>
----> 1 tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets(q="oranges", tweet_mode='extended', lang='en')).items()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py in __init__(self, method, *args, **kwargs)
     38                 raise TweepyException('Invalid pagination mode.')
     39         else:
---> 40             raise TweepyException('This method does not perform pagination')
     41 
     42     def pages(self, limit=inf):

TweepyException: This method does not perform pagination
```

I do not know why this is. I can still post Tweets using the `api.update_status()` function. Please help. Here is my code. As you can see, the setup is correct; it is only this function that is returning the error.

```
from config import *
import tweepy
import datetime

consumer_key= 'CONSUMER KEY HERE'
consumer_secret= 'CONSUMER KEY SECRET HERE'
access_token= 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE'
access_token_secret= 'ACCESS TOKEN SECRET HERE'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful")
except:
    print("Authentication Error")

tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets(q="oranges", tweet_mode='extended', lang='en')).items()
```

If there is an error in the function or the code itself, can you please write a correct version? I'm trying to gather Tweet data for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the result of the call to / invocation of `API.search_tweets`, rather than the method itself, to `Cursor`.

See [Tweepy's Pagination documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/pagination.html) for an example of how to use `Cursor`.